# awk | split the column and map with substring

Tags: awk

File1 (Big file with millions of records)

> 1,5,404920012,type1,info1
>   4,2,10000234,type2,info2
>   2,3,40492001223,type3,info3
>   3,1,50492001223,type4,info4

File2 (small file with only 10 lines)

> 40492=product1
>   10000=product2

Output

> 1,5,404920012,type1,product1,info1
>   4,2,10000234,type2,product2,info2
>   2,3,40492001223,type3,product1,info3
>   3,1,50492001223,type4,NOMATCH,info4

Notes:
I want to compare first 5 character of 3rd column from file1 to file 2
after matching fields, product1 should be in 5th column of output

What I have Tried:
Though I am new in awk advance programming, but what I have a learnt so far.. I can merge 2 files as follows:

> BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
>               FNR == NR {
>         x=$1;
>         $1 = "";
>         a[x] = $0;
>         next
>       }
>       {
>         if($3 in a)print $0","a[$3];
>         else print $0",,";
>       }

But issue with this is.. I dont know how to pass different FS (= in case of 2nd file)for 2nd file and how to combine substr function echo 404920012 | awk '{print substr($0,1,5)}'
in if condition..

Comment: I have updated what I have tried and where I am stuck below my query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
awk -f p.awk file2 file1
```

where `p.awk` is

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
    OFS=","
}

NR==FNR {
    split($1,a,"=")
    keys[a[1]]=a[2]
    next
}
{
    k=substr($3,1,5)
    if (k in keys) 
        p=keys[k]
    else
        p="NOMATCH"
    $4=$4 OFS p
    print
}
```

with output:

```
1,5,404920012,type1,product1,info1
4,2,10000234,type2,product2,info2
2,3,40492001223,type3,product1,info3
3,1,50492001223,type4,NOMATCH,info4
```

Comment: Thanks Håkon .. that really helped..   but is it possible that while specifying print $1,$2,$3,$4,p,$5.. I can specify range as well? for example if my file has 100 fields.. so instead of writing individual column name, we write $1-$4,p,$5-$100..?

Comment: also could you explain this - keys[a[1]]=a[2]

Comment: Thanks.. not sure how expensive loop it would be in if file is really big.. in this case it will loop every line for every column.. But anyways.. I got the really meaningful answer.. thanks

Comment: @VipinChoudhary The `keys[a[1]]=a[2]` builds an associative array `keys` from the result of the `split` function..

Comment: @VipinChoudhary I found a better solution, see update.. Now you do not have to use a `for` loop at all :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a case when, since it varies between input files, you want to set FS to the appropriate value between files  rather than up front in the awk command arguments using `-F` or `-v FS=`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{
    key = substr($3,1,5)
    $5 = (key in map ? map[key] : "NOMATCH") OFS $5
    print
}
' FS='=' File2 FS=',' OFS=',' File1
```

Just in case: This is just briefer than the answer you selected, functionally it's equivalent so please don't change to select this one.